# Importing data from csv to database using Python

Tags: python, sql, cs50

I need to create a database using info from a csv file, format:
`name,house,birth`
example:

```
Adelaide Murton,Slytherin,1982  
Adrian Pucey,Slytherin,1977
```

Then I need to export to the database after splitting the name in the following format:
`first | middle | last | house | birth`

Below is my code; it exports like 1st row only first name, 2nd row only middle name,  3d row only last name, 4th row only house , etc. and everything else appears NULL. I end up having 792 rows instead of 40 in my database.  [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7eRq.jpg)

```
import csv
import sys
import cs50

db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: import.py file.csv")
    
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        x = row["name"].split()
        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", x[0], x[1] if len(x)==3 else None, x[2] if len(x)==3 else x[1], row["house"], row["birth"])
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what your output looks like?

Comment: Did you try to do some debugging? Are the values of `row` and `x` in the loop what you expect them to be?

Comment: I added the output image; yes, I did the debugging and the values of `row` and `x` are what they should be.

Comment: And do you have 40 loop iterations as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the students table is empty before running import, otherwise all the rows from all the attempts, buggy or not, are in the database. A bug that creates the described output would only insert approx 280 rows. (7 db rows per 1 csv row)

Comment: Yes, that was it, after I emptied it it worked. Thank you!